# Using unique IP per tab/page with Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, proxies

I need a different proxy per page/tab in puppeteer.

I found a similar answer that had a NPM package named `puppeteer-page-proxy` 
but it seems to have some issues at the moment, but I'm looking for the same exact feature.

Is there an alternative working package or even a way to do this without any packages natively inside of puppeteer?

Answer (score 1):

Those issues were caused by recent puppeteer updates in version 3.2.0 in which they switched to another event emitter library and that produced breaking changes.

However they quickly [reversed the switch](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5944#issuecomment-637400760) in 3.3.0 so you can just update your puppeteer version:

```
npm update puppeteer
```

Comment: Thanks i was actually using a version of node that was not supported. Updated and is working fine. thanks for the help